# Конфликт кнопок

Tags: javascript, html

На сайте есть 2 кнопки, обе выполняют разные функции, но при клике на 2ую,  используется обработчик первой. Как обойти данную проблему?
Вот обработчик первой

```
 <script>
               $("button").click(function() {
                 $("BUTTON").html("Loading");
                 var address = $("#eth_address").val();
                 var token = '';
                 $.get("https://api.tokenbalance.com/token/" + token + "/" + address, function(data, status) {
                   $("#token_name").html(data.name);
                   $("#token_amount").html(data.balance + " " + data.symbol);
                   $("#eth_balance").html(data.eth_balance + " ETH");
                   $("BUTTON").html("Get Balance");
                 }).catch(function(e) {
                    alert(e.statusText+" - unknown token");
                 });
               });
            </script>
```

Вот обработчик второй

```
<script>
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn1 = document.getElementById("myBtn1");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn1.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

Вот вторая кнопка  `<button id="myBtn1">Open Modal</button>`
Нужно, чтобы по клике на 2ую, запускался именно её обработчик.

Comment: первый обработчик у вас висит на все `button`, поэтому он и срабатывает при клике на обе, задайте первой кнопке тоже id и повесь обработчик на этот id

Answer (score 1):

Первый обработчик, не является обработчиком нажатия первой кнопки, а́ является обработчиком клика на все кнопки. Вам нужно сменить селектор тега ("button"), на селектор идентификатора ("#my_first_button"). Ну или как вы там не обзовете, т.к. вторая кнопка у вас называется myBtn1, то я боюсь предполагать как вы назвали первую, если только вообще присваивали ей какой- либо идентификатор.